# how to fetch log of package while calling from diffrent database?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dblink

I am executing procedure A where I am calling procedure B from diffrent database over dblink. the dbms log of procedure A is getting printed but log of procedure B is not getting printed.

I tried copying the log buffer using dbms_output.get_line and store it in file.but buffer in second database dosent contain anything.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
name VARCHAR2(50) := 'File';
    lines dbms_output.chararr;
    num_lines NUMBER;
    l_done    NUMBER;
    l_file utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
    l_file := utl_file.fopen('TMP', 'foo.log', 'A');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I am in : '|| name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Again I am in : '|| name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Again I am in : '|| name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Again I am in : '|| name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Again I am in : '|| name);
    num_lines := 5;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES(lines,num_lines);
    FOR i IN 1..num_lines
    LOOP
       utl_file.put_line(l_file, lines(i));
    END LOOP;
    utl_file.fflush(l_file);
    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
END;
```

Comment: I think you're missing `dbms_output.enable()` at the start of your procedure. If you don't open the buffer the subsequent calls to `put_line()` are writing to nowhere (like directing stdout to `\dev\null`). You'll also need `dbms_output.disable()` at the end.

Comment: I have dbms_output.enable in the orignal code.above given is just an example .

Comment: These things depend heavily on the precise details of your architecture. If you don't provide a complete and accurate question then all we can do is guess, probably wrongly. Which is a waste of everybody's time and won't get you a solution in a timely manner.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to `set serverout on` over DB link.

See my example below:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE
    LINES    VARCHAR2(1000);
    STATUS   INT;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE@DB1; -- enabling serveroutput over DB link
    B@DB1; -- calling procedure over DB link
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE@DB1 ( LINES, STATUS ); -- getting all the lines from buffer of db link
        EXIT WHEN STATUS != 0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LINES); -- printing lines from db link to current db
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Cheers!!